# How do I call a PHP function with GET parameters

Tags: php, function, parameters

How do I call the function "upgrade_instance_at_date" within the "schedule_all"(both of them are in the same file) function, but not with cURL.Thank you in advance, I'm new :D

```
    public function schedule_all()

{
          
        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/production/customer/upgrade_instance_at_date?domain_name=$machines->domain_name&date=$date");
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
       
}
```

Comment: this is called "include" which is one of the most basic operators in PHP

Comment: for clarity `include` is an expression, not operator.

Comment: if this function is in the same file, then you *just call* it